# Investigate how many endomorphisms $f \in L(\mathbb R[x]_{3})$ meet the conditions

Tags: linear-algebra

> Investigate how many endomorphisms $f \in L(\mathbb R[x]_{3})$ meet the conditions:
>  (i) $\ker f =  \operatorname{span}(1,x)$, 
>  (ii) $f\circ f=f$, 
>  (iii) $f(x^{2})=1-x+x^{2}$, 
>  (iv) if $f(x^{3})=p$ then $p(1)=p'(1)=0$.
> Find a Jordan's matrix and basis for for each such endomorphism

I know that in (ii) $f \in L(\mathbb R[x]_{3})$ is a projection for a some subspace $U$ along the subspace $V$. But I think it is impossible to such a special observation is crucial in this task because it does not seem so complicated. 
At the same time, we did not do anything similar on the lectures, so I have no knowledge about it.

Can you help me?

Comment: Are (i)-(iv) separate questions, or should you look for endomorphisms which satisfy all of them at the same time?

Comment: Could you answer to Arthur, please ? If you must meet the 5 conditions, consider a generic element under the form $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ then "translate" all your conditions into the "language of $\mathbb{R}^n$" ; in particular, accumulate information about the matrix which corresponds to $f$.

Comment: @Arthur I am not sure how to understand the content of this task, but it seems to me that each case is separate

Comment: I don't think so (see my first sentence in my answer.

Comment: I have rectified my answer at its end (no longer two but one solution) taking into account a restriction pinpointed by @egreg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditions (i)-...-(v) have to be considered **jointly**. We are going to show that they determine a single  matrix.

We will consider the matrix $M$ describing the transformation with respect to the (canonical) basis $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}.$
The columns of such a matrix associated with a linear operation are given by the images of the basis'elements. Let us show in a first step that :

$$M=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&1&d\\
0&0&-1&(c-2d)\\
0&0&1&(-2c+d)\\
0&0&0&c\end{pmatrix}.$$

Explanations :

Columns 1 and 2 : they are both zero because condition (i) says that $f(1)=0=0+0x+0x^2+0x^3$ and $f(x)=0=0+0x+0x^2+0x^3$.

Column 3 : (condition (iii)) coefficients of $1-1x+1x^2+0x^3$.

Column 4 : condition (iv) amounts to say that $1$ is a *double root* of $p$ ; thus the image can be written $p=(x-1)^2(cx+d)=d+(c-2d)x+(-2c+d)x^2+cx^3.$

Now, we must take into account the fact that $M^2=M$ (condition (ii)) with :

$$M^2=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&1&(d - 2c + cd)\\
0&0&-1&(2c - d + c^2 - 2cd))\\
0&0&1&(c + 1)(d-2c)\\
0&0&0&c^2\end{pmatrix}.$$

Identifiying $M^2$ and $M$ leads to a first condition $c^2=c$, thus necessarily $c=0$ or $c=1$. Let us consider each of these cases :

- if $c=0$, whatever the value of $d$, all other constraints are verified BUT we get in this way a fourth column proportional to the third one ;  thus we would have Rank(M)=1 ; this comes in contradiction with the somewhat hidden condition : $\dim \ker f = 2 \implies Rank(f)=4-2=2$. (I am indebted here to the solution by @Egreg : I hadn't seen at first this condition). Thus we must rule out this case.
- if $c=1$, we deduce without difficulty that $d=2$ matches all conditions, giving the rank-2 unique solution :

$$M=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&1&2\\
0&0&-1&-3\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

I think that the Jordan form will not be difficult. Btw, what are the eigenvalues of a projector ?

Comment: Can you say, 4 hours later,  if this solution aggrees you ? You aren't new on this site : you know it is done for exchanges, It's not just an anonymous booth.

Comment: So If I understand well - you finds matrix of linear transformation in use of given information. You can do this because in each step you use some vectors (there presented as polynomials) which together creates a base of $R[x]_3$. Is that right? After that you have all things to prepare Jordan Matrix, right? Ps: sorry but I am already a bit overtired, I run with the material and I can not cover everything at once

Comment: Thanks for answering. You are excused. Answers : Right. Right (you do it just as if the original problem had been presented in $\mathbb{R}^4$).

Comment: Okay, but I have one more question - to step with column 4. You have seen that it is double root - but let say that I didn't see that. So I have decided to put $ f(x^3) = p(x) = ax^9 +bx^6 + cx^3 + d $ and then check $p(1)=0$ and $p(-1)=0$ And then I get this column $[c+2d,-2c-3d,c,d]^T $ and I don't know if I have take mistake or my approach is not correct (but it seems to be reasonable)

Comment: No : notation $f(x^3)$ is misleading, but shouldn't be interpreted like that: it is the effect of the transformation of $x^3$ by the linear operator$f$. Your intepretation cannot be the right one : we must stay in the vector space of polynomials with degree $\leq 3$.

Comment: but if i take the  $f(x^3)=a+bx+cx^2+dx^3 $ I get the same result

Answer (score 0):

We know that $f(1)=0$, $f(x)=0$, $f(x^2)=1-x-x^2$; set $f(x^3)=a+bx+cx^2+dx^3$.

You might be confused by polynomial notation; here it might be convenient to set $v_1=1$, $v_2=x$, $v_3=x^2$ and $v_4=x^3$; then the above statements become more “linear algebra like”:
\begin{cases}
f(v_1)=0 \\
f(v_2)=0 \\
f(v_3)=v_1-v_2+v_3 \\
f(v_4)=av_1+bv_2+cv_3+dv_4
\end{cases}
Since $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}_3[x]$, the above characterizes the linear map $f$, provided we determine $a,b,c,d$ so that conditions (i)–(v) are satisfied.

The matrix with respect to the basis $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ is
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & a \\
0 & 0 & -1 & b \\
0 & 0 & 1 & c \\
0 & 0 & 0 & d
\end{bmatrix}
$$
We can compute $A^2$:
$$
A^2=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & ad+c \\
0 & 0 & -1 & bd-c \\
0 & 0 & 1 & cd+c \\
0 & 0 & 0 & d^2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Since we need $A=A^2$, we deduce
\begin{cases}
ad+c=a \\
bd-c=b \\
cd+c=c \\
d^2=d
\end{cases}
that immediately splits into $d=0$ or $d=1$.

#### Case $d=0$

We get $a=c$ and $b=-c$. Therefore $f(v_4)=c(v_1-v_2+v_3)$. In terms of polynomials, we have $f(v_4)=p$, where $p(x)=c(1-x+x^2)$. We have $p(1)=c$ and condition (v) forces $c=0$. This cannot be the case, because the rank would be $1$, contrary to the requirement that $\dim\ker f=2$.

#### Case $d=1$

We get $c=0$. Thus $f(v_4)=av_1+bv_2+v_4$ and so $p(x)=a+bx+x^3$. The condition $p(1)=0$ yields $a+b+1=0$; the condition $p'(1)=0$ yields $b+3=0$, so $b=-3$ and $a=2$.

#### Final discussion

The matrix of $f$ is
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & -3 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The matrix has a double eigenvalue $0$ and a double eigenvalue $1$. Since also the eigenspace relative to $1$ has dimension $2$, the matrix is diagonalizable.

Comment: You are right, case $d=0$ has to be ruled out : my solution (that I have rectified) was an answer to a milder condition : (i) $ ker f \supseteq span\{1,x\}$ .